# Do I need to begin from the first game for the story of Assassin's Creed?

Tags: assassins-creed-series

I've got the original Assassin's Creed game *somewhere* in my house. When I finish a game I then intend to play it, but it seems to "move" and so I begin another game instead. Been going on for two years+.

My question is, should I bother with the first Assassin's Creed game? I know there are a lot more out there now. Will I miss a lot of the story if I were to jump straight to the second game? Or Unity?

Should I begin from the first game or are the later ones so much better that missing some of the story does not matter?

Comment: Depends if you're enjoying the game! The first game is a bit more repetitive than the later ones. Alternatively, you could [watch the cutscenes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2BKdf-tBgM) from it without having to play through!

Comment: This might get closed because it is opion based. If you want the full experience you just need to start with part 1, it will make the sequels more enjoyable too. Myself I started at part 2 because I've read it improved tons in gameplay compared to part 1, which is considered pretty boring by many people. I've looked up a summary of AC1 and I understood the story just fine. They're great games, I'd recommend starting with 2 if you plan on playing brotherhood and revelations as well, as those follow the Ezio story unlike the parts after revelations.

Comment: I also started at AC2, and I've never played the first game. I would say, in my opinion, 2 is the best place to start. You can definitely get the gist of what the first game is about, without having to go through the repetition of the first. Two is an excellent game (the only game I got platinum on on PS3) and sets up the series well. The subsequent games carry the story on well, and also add multiplayer, which was very good in the Ezio series follow ups.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Coming from an Assassin's Creed Veteran I'll say you have some choices.

### 1st Choice (Not caring for the Story):

If you really don't care about much of the story (which I assume isn't the case because you made this question) you can easily jump into any game.

Maybe if you jump into Brotherhood or Revelations without any previous knowledge you'll feel quite lost.

### 2nd Choice:

If you care about the Story and don't really feel like playing the first game you can opt for Assassin's Creed 3 which gives a brief but good sum of the story of the Modern Times of the Series.

But to answer you answer completely, I feel like the later games are much much better and the story in Assassin's Creed 1 isn't substantial BUT it comes down to what you want to do.

Like the 3rd Crusade era? I would advise you to play it.
Like a good story with some philosophical thoughts? I would advise you to play it.
Don't have much time to play and you have to choose between 1 or a later game? Well I would advise you to play the later game and read a synopsis online or see a walkthrough online.

If you want me to explain further and want more convincing please say so in the comments.

Comment: I play games for the stories these days - I got older, have got less time so prefer "Normal" difficulty to go through without too much hassle and see the story. So it is important, though if I am going to spend hours playing something boring... that doesn't help me enjoy it. I'll feel like it is a chore.

Answer (score 1):

This is matter of player opinion. There is a story in Assassins Creed which involves a person in experiment where scientist inspect human dna and get's back into the history seeings the events by itself. If you just want to enjoy the gameplay mechanics and the story which happens in actual gameplay, you can just start any series. But if you want to know the other story which happens behind the "curtains" you need to start from part 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex question to answer because of the series' approach to story telling.

**Short answer**

In my considered opinion:

- By not playing the earlier games you will miss out on some of the story.
- The story that you miss out on doesn't matter.

**Long answer**

Each game tells two stories - one set in modern times, one set in a particular period in history. The series' central conceit involves the characters in the modern day using technology to explore the memories of their ancestors in virtual environments, as part of a secret war between two factions (The Assasins and the Knights Templar) which has been going on for hundreds of years.

In each game there's one main story arc told from the perspective of the ancestor whose memories are being explored, set in the time and place they lived. The majority of the gameplay happens from this perspective. While some the characters in these games do cross over (most notably, Ezio Auditore is the primary protagonist for the historic parts of AC2, Brotherhood *and* Revelations), the relevant parts of the narrative tend to be largely self-contained, and can be enjoyed without the context of the rest of the series.

Meanwhile, the story of the modern day characters begins in AC1 and is progressed by each game in the series. It largely seek to justify the reasons for exploring the memories of the character in the historic parts of the game, and usually there will be some sections of gameplay where you'll need to control characters in this story in order to progress. To follow this plot from the beginning you'll need to start from the beginning of the series.

**In my opinion then...** the modern day story is pretty crazy, starting with megacorporations and conspiracy theories, and quickly moving on to ancient alien races and beyond. The games in the series do try to summarise the story so far for new players, but whether they succeed is debatable. However, the game will tell you what you need to do to advance the modern day part of the story even if you may not fully understand why you need to do it, and since the majority of any given game will be spent in the historic setting anyway, it's debatable whether missing parts of the story will effect your overall enjoyment of the game.